# Using ? in sql create '' around parameter

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I try to create a query like such:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE %?%
```

The error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'word'%' at line 1

How to avoid the two apostrophes?

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE ?
```

but then I would need an exact match.

Comment: You need single quotes around the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

However, I would suggest that you append the wildcards in the app and simply use:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @gordon. Concat works fine. Can you elobrate a bit more on what you mean with appending the wildcards in the app?

Comment: @Nothere . . . In the code the sends the parameter, put `'%'` at the beginning and end right in the parameter.

Comment: Ha! That's clever, @gordon. What would be the advantage over concat? Just speed?

Comment: @Nothere . . . It simplifies the query logic.   But I don't have a strong opinion on this.